# NumberofLoops for Audio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

When repeat button is hit for the first time then it should run infinite times and when it is hit  for second time then it should not repeat audio rather it should stop looping. . Below is the code it works very well for the first time but when it is pressed again it is not stopping looping.

```
BOOL isFirstTime;

@interface English : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate,

-(void) RepeatAction:(id)sender{

if(isFirstTime == YES){

     player.numberOfLoops = -1;


} else {

    player.numberOfLoops = 0;
}

}

- (void)playAction:(id)sender
{
    if([player isPlaying])
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [player pause];

    }else{
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audiopause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [player play];
        slidertimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:slidertimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        timer = slidertimer;


    }}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Show us where you are setting your boolean, and running the loop.

Comment: Defining Bool in h file before interface and setting in m file in viewdidload isFirstTime = YES;

Comment: I don't see any point where you set isFirstTime to NO. So of course your loop is going to just keep running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void) RepeatAction:(id)sender{
    if(isFirstTime){  // even here you need not to compare with == YES
         player.numberOfLoops = -1;
         isFirstTime = NO;
    } else {
        player.numberOfLoops = 0;
        isFirstTime = YES;
    }
}
```